# random effect variance as pseudo-rsquared in GLMM

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model, r-squared, glmm

Suppose I have data on the abundance of a species across multiple sites that differ in some covariate of interest. Suppose that the logarithm of the abundance (logAbun) meets assumptions for linear regression, with homoskedastic normal residuals.

We could then write the model

```
logAbun ~ normal(mu, sigma)
mu = alpha + beta*covariate
```

We can analyze this model in the standard way, and we might report R-squared as (among other things) a measure of the percent variance in logAbun explained by the covariate.

Now suppose that instead of measuring the true abundance, we instead have samples (counts) that are Poisson variates with means governed by the true abundance. It would be quite natural to extend our model as follows:

```
count ~ Poisson(abundance)
log(abundance) ~ normal(mu, sigma)
mu = alpha + beta*covariate
```

This is a hierarchical model where abundance (and logAbun) is latent. Note that this model is precisely a Poisson GLMM with the canonical log link and a random effect of observation.

**So here's the question:**
It seems natural that we could *still* ask what percentage of the variation in the latent logAbun is explained by the covariate. And it seems that all we'd need to do is re-fit the model without the covariate (but still including the random effect of observation), and compare the random-effect variance of the "null" model with no covariate to the model with the covariate. Moreover, it seems we can use an analogous procedure to analyze many or most GLMs--as long as we're willing to fit a random effect of observation. That is, we just fit a hierarchical model so that the top level looks like a standard linear regression on a latent parameter, and we calculate an r-squared value for this standard (but latent) regression. **Yet I've never seen anybody do this!** Am I just missing that people do this regularly?  Is this a Very Bad Idea for some reason (i.e. is it likely to fail to provide a correct/useful picture of how much variation in logAbun is explained by the covariate)?

**Note:** if we can avoid it, let's not get hung up on potential difficulties of estimating the correct random-effect variance (or its uncertainty).  Assuming we have a valid estimation procedure that we trust (if nothing else, Bayesian estimation with a good choice of prior), is there some reason why this analysis is likely to fail to provide a correct/useful picture of how much variation in abundance is explained by the covariate?

Comment: have you seen https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsif.2017.0213 ?

Comment: @BenBolker I had not seen this paper; thanks very much. It seems to me that despite this paper's stated focus on GLMMs, the methods that the authors propose are in general a powerful way to understand percent variance explained in all GLMs; that is, for any GLM, add a random effect of observation so that the top level of the hierarchy is a latent linear regression, and compute R-squared for that regression. I find it surprising that this hasn't become a "standard approach" for obtaining psudo-r-squared in a GLM context...

Comment: ... but maybe I'm being naive having come of age as a data analyst only after the proliferation of powerful, reliable, and accessible tools to fit GLMMs.

Comment: My opinion about pseudo-R^2s is that there are already quite a few reasonable proposals (Nagelkerke, Cox and Snell, McFadden, Efron), but none dominates [they all answer slightly different questions]. Given that I don't think there is a uniquely best answer to "variance explained" for GLM(M)s, I've never felt the need to add another possibility (similar to https://xkcd.com/927/ )

Comment: @BenBolker Fair enough. As far as I've understood in the past, the various proposals you mention seem to have more to do with R-squared as a measure of goodness-of-fit than with R-squared as a measure of percent variance explained. The question "how much of the variation in abundance is explained by the covariate" remains meaningful in the GLMM context, and moreover I think the meaning corresponds precisely to our intuitions about percent-variance explained in a linear regression context.